# Could Amazon S3 Presigned URL be generated so a user can read a file but not download it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, salesforce, pre-signed-url

We have a requirement to provide a user with temporary access to video files stored in Amazon S3. Users with a presigned URL should be able to play a video but not download it.

Is there any option to generate a presigned URL so users can play a video in a browser without the "Download" option?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between 'reading' and 'downloading' the response to a URL.

You could choose to **stream** content, which means that the browser actively requests segments of the file rather than simply receiving the whole file. This avoids the ability to 'download' a file, but smart people can still obtain the entire contents by requesting all the segments. Not even Netflix can prevent this from happening.